# Verifying my understanding of replicating portfolio, hedging and option pricing

Tags: options, option-pricing, risk-neutral-measure

Under risk neutral measure, we use replicating portfolio to mimic the value  of derivative (for example European options).

Many literatures use the word "hedging" to describe the replicating portfolio which confuses me.
As the replicated portfolio's value mimics the value of an option, how can such portfolio be hedging? Isn't hedging be a way to recover/minimise lost when an option's value diminish (if I long it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the risk-neutral measure, an European option is hedged with a replicating portfolio. The combined portfolio evolves at the riskless rate.

For example, a short European call option with underlying stock X is hedged with a replicating portfolio of long continuously rebalanced delta-times-stock X, which generates a portfolio that evolves at the riskless rate. This is a hedge because when a stock X appreciates in value and causes a loss to the short European call option position, the long position of delta-times-stock X appreciates in value, hedging the original option position.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So the replicating portfolio would differ for a Euro call option, depending on whether I long it or short it? If so, ow do I show it in calculation? ( Take binomial pricing for concreteness)

Comment: In short, yes. If you have a long European option, the hedge would be short delta-times-stock continuously rebalanced. I only watched snippets of this video, but it seems quite close to an example I went through myself before (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7kOPxvRbRI&ab_channel=BionicTurtle).